# Breaking Groups into 3 buckets based on whether or not one field has any 0s

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have events that are being treated differently based on whether or not expenses have 0 attendees.

Each event has a unique code with several expense line items. If the `attendee` field has ALL `0` for each expense in this event code, then I need to append the `method` field to say `method 1`, for each expense with this event code.

If ANY of the line items with the same event code have a `0` but the sum of all of them is `> 0` then I need to append the `method` field to say `method 2`

If ALL of the line items are `> 0` then I need to append the `method` field to say `method 3`

Thanks for any help! Sorry for not having more code in this, I am at a loss.

Sample Data:

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Sample data and a table schema would go a long way toward helping here.

Comment: Thank you. I just changed OP to add image link.

Comment: Sample data should be posted as a text table in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MS Access does not support aggregation within `update` queries, one possible alternative might be to use the domain aggregate functions [`DMin`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dmin-dmax-functions-f5c6de87-8752-4f29-ab4b-c554053d299f) & [`DMax`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dmin-dmax-functions-f5c6de87-8752-4f29-ab4b-c554053d299f), e.g.:

```sql
update YourTable t
set t.method = 
iif
(
    dmax("attendee","YourTable","EventID = '" & t.EventID & "'")=0,
    1,
    iif
    (
        dmin("attendee","YourTable","EventID = '" & t.EventID & "'")=0,
        2,
        3
    )
)
```

This assumes that `attendee` will never be negative.

Alternatively, if you wanted to avoid the domain aggregate functions, you could write the values using three separate update queries - one for each `method` value:

**Method = 1**

```sql
update YourTable t
set t.method = 1
where not exists (select 1 from YourTable t2 where t2.eventid = t.eventid and t2.attendee > 0)
```

**Method = 2**

```sql
update YourTable t
set t.method = 2
where exists (select 1 from YourTable t2 where t2.eventid = t.eventid and t2.attendee > 0)
  and exists (select 1 from YourTable t2 where t2.eventid = t.eventid and t2.attendee = 0)
```

**Method = 3**

```sql
update YourTable t
set t.method = 3
where not exists (select 1 from YourTable t2 where t2.eventid = t.eventid and t2.attendee = 0)
```

In all of the above, change all occurrences of `YourTable` to the name of your table, and the fields `attendee` & `EventID` to suit your field names.